# Getting value with Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I was searching quite a lot for finding a solution for my problem and tried a lot with related solutions but they all don´t work for me so i guess i´m missing smth. and would be glad if someone would help me out. So maybe my code first:

```
    package Test;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.FindElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Wait;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class oeffnen {

    WebDriver driver;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-11.0.2\\bin\\geckodriver.exe");
            WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.get("https://www.bet365.com/#/IP/");
            driver.findElement(By.className("lpdgl")).click();
            driver.get("https://www.bet365.com/#/IP/");
            driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            String value = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.ipo-Competition:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(2)")).getText();
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("D:\\Test.txt");
            writer.println(value);
            writer.close();


    }

    private static void WebDriverWait() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

So i´m trying to get the rate that a certain team wins game. Tried several ways of by.xpath and .getText() and ended up now with by.cssselector and still getting no value in my Test.txt. Or just isn´t it possible at this page (blocked)?

I would be really glad if someone could help me here.

Page: https://www.bet365.com/#/IP/

In regards

*edit 13.03.2019*

here is the html code of that page:

```
<div>
<div class="wc-WebConsoleModule ">
<div>
<div class="hm-HeaderModule ">
<div class="hm-HeaderModule_Primary ">
<div class="hm-BigButtons hm-BigButtons-noscrollernative "><nav class="hm-BigButtons_Inner "><a class="hm-BigButton ">Sport</a><a class="hm-BigButton hm-BigButton_Highlight ">Live</a><a class="hm-BigButton ">Casino</a><a class="hm-BigButton ">Live-Casino</a><a class="hm-BigButton ">Spiele</a><a class="hm-BigButton ">Poker</a><a class="hm-BigButton ">Vegas</a></nav></div>
<div class="hm-HeaderModule_UserAdmin ">
<div class="hm-Login ">
<div class="hm-Login_UserNameWrapper "><input class="hm-Login_InputField " type="text" />
<div class="hm-Login_InputText ">Jetzt Anmelden</div>
</div>
<div class="hm-Login_PasswordWrapper "><input class="hm-Login_InputField " type="text" /><input class="hm-Login_InputField Hidden " type="password" /><button class="hm-Login_LoginBtn " tabindex="0">OK</button>
<div class="hm-Login_InputText ">Daten vergessen?</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="hm-HeaderModule_Secondary hm-HeaderModule_Secondary-search ">
<div class="sml-SearchHeader ">
<div class="sml-SearchHeader_SearchIcon ">&nbsp;</div>
<input class="sml-SearchTextInput " type="text" placeholder="Suchen" /></div>
<div class="hm-HeaderModule_Menus ">
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<a class="hm-HeaderModule_Link ">Spielsuchtpr&auml;vention</a><a class="hm-HeaderModule_Link ">Live-Bilder</a><a class="hm-HeaderModule_Link ">Hilfe</a>
<div>
<div class="hm-LanguageDropDownSelections hm-DropDownSelections "><a class="hm-DropDownSelections_Button hm-DropDownSelections_DropLink ">Sprache<span class="hm-DropDownSelections_Highlight ">Deutsch</span></a></div>
</div>
<div>
<div class="hm-OddsDropDownSelections hm-DropDownSelections "><a class="hm-DropDownSelections_Button hm-DropDownSelections_DropLink ">Quoten<span class="hm-DropDownSelections_Highlight ">Dezimal</span></a></div>
</div>
<div class="hm-ServicesDropDownSelections hm-DropDownSelections "><a class="hm-DropDownSelections_Button hm-DropDownSelections_DropLink hm-DropDownSelections_Solo ">Service</a></div>
</div>
<div class="hm-HeaderModule_TimeLastLogin "><time class="hm-Clock ">20:19:32 CET</time></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="wc-PageView ">
<div class="wc-PageView_Main wc-InPlayPage_MainContainer ">
<div>
<div class="ip-InPlayModule ">
<div class="ip-ControlBar ">
<div class="ip-ControlBar_BBarItem wl-ButtonBar_Selected ">&Uuml;bersicht</div>
<div class="ip-ControlBar_BBarItem ">Einzelanzeige</div>
<div class="ip-ControlBar_BBarItem ">Kalender</div>
</div>
<div class="ipo-OverViewView ">
<div class="ipo-OverViewNativeScroller ipo-OverViewNativeScroller-scrollable ">
<div class="ipo-OverViewNativeScroller_ContentContainer " style="max-height: 424.3333282470703px;">
<div class="ipo-OverViewView_ContentContainer ipo-OverViewNativeScroller_Content ipo-ClassificationBarScrollable_RightArrowVisible ">
<div class="ipo-ClassificationBar ">
<div class="ipo-ClassificationBarScrollable ipo-ClassificationBarScrollable-notransition ">
<div class="ipo-ClassificationBarScrollable_LeftArrow ipo-ClassificationBarScrollable_Hidden ">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="ipo-ClassificationBarScrollable_HScroll">
<div class="ipo-ClassificationBar_ButtonContainer ipo-ClassificationBarScrollable_ScrollContent ipo-ClassificationBarScrollable_ScrollContentNoAnimation ">
<div class="ipo-ClassificationBarButtonBase ">
<div class="ipo-ClassificationBarButtonBase_Icon ">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="ipo-ClassificationBarButtonBase_Label ">Favoriten</div>
</div>
<div class="ipo-ClassificationBarButtonBase ipo-ClassificationBarButtonBase_Selected ipo-ClassificationBarButtonBase_Selected-1 ">
<div class="ipo-ClassificationBarButtonBase_Icon ">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="ipo-ClassificationBarButtonBase_Label ">Fu&szlig;ball</div>
</div>
<div class="ipo-ClassificationBarButtonBase ">
<div class="ipo-ClassificationBarButtonBase_Icon ">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="ipo-ClassificationBarButtonBase_Label ">Tennis</div>
</div>
<div class="ipo-ClassificationBarButtonBase ">
<div class="ipo-ClassificationBarButtonBase_Icon ">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="ipo-ClassificationBarButtonBase_Label ">Badminton</div>
</div>
<div class="ipo-ClassificationBarButtonBase ">
<div class="ipo-ClassificationBarButtonBase_Icon ">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="ipo-ClassificationBarButtonBase_Label ">Baseball</div>
</div>
<div class="ipo-ClassificationBarButtonBase ">
<div class="ipo-ClassificationBarButtonBase_Icon ">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="ipo-ClassificationBarButtonBase_Label ">Basketball</div>
</div>
<div class="ipo-ClassificationBarButtonBase ">
<div class="ipo-ClassificationBarButtonBase_Icon ">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="ipo-ClassificationBarButtonBase_Label ">E-Sports</div>
</div>
<div class="ipo-ClassificationBarButtonBase ">
<div class="ipo-ClassificationBarButtonBase_Icon ">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="ipo-ClassificationBarButtonBase_Label ">Eishockey</div>
</div>
<div class="ipo-ClassificationBarButtonBase ">
<div class="ipo-ClassificationBarButtonBase_Icon ">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="ipo-ClassificationBarButtonBase_Label ">Floorball</div>
</div>
<div class="ipo-ClassificationBarButtonBase ">
<div class="ipo-ClassificationBarButtonBase_Icon ">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="ipo-ClassificationBarButtonBase_Label ">Futsal</div>
</div>
<div class="ipo-ClassificationBarButtonBase ">
<div class="ipo-ClassificationBarButtonBase_Icon ">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="ipo-ClassificationBarButtonBase_Label ">Handball</div>
</div>
<div class="ipo-ClassificationBarButtonBase ">
<div class="ipo-ClassificationBarButtonBase_Icon ">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="ipo-ClassificationBarButtonBase_Label ">Pferderennen</div>
</div>
<div class="ipo-ClassificationBarButtonBase ">
<div class="ipo-ClassificationBarButtonBase_Icon ">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="ipo-ClassificationBarButtonBase_Label ">Snooker</div>
</div>
<div class="ipo-ClassificationBarButtonBase ">
<div class="ipo-ClassificationBarButtonBase_Icon ">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="ipo-ClassificationBarButtonBase_Label ">Squash</div>
</div>
<div class="ipo-ClassificationBarButtonBase ">
<div class="ipo-ClassificationBarButtonBase_Icon ">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="ipo-ClassificationBarButtonBase_Label ">Tischtennis</div>
</div>
<div class="ipo-ClassificationBarButtonBase ">
<div class="ipo-ClassificationBarButtonBase_Icon ">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="ipo-ClassificationBarButtonBase_Label ">Volleyball</div>
</div>
<div class="ipo-ClassificationBarButtonBase ">
<div class="ipo-ClassificationBarButtonBase_Icon ">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="ipo-ClassificationBarButtonBase_Label ">Windhundrennen</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="ipo-ClassificationBarScrollable_RightArrow ">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="ipo-OverViewDetail ">
<div class="ipo-OverViewDetail_Container ipo-Classification ">
<div class="ipo-ClassificationHeader_Header ipo-ClassificationHeader_Header-1 ipo-ClassificationHeader_Header-lightgreenborder ipo-ClassificationHeader_Header-moremarkets ">
<div class="ipo-ClassificationHeader_HeaderLabel ">Fu&szlig;ball</div>
<div class="ipo-ClassificationHeader_EventButtonWrapper ">
<div class="ipo-ClassificationHeader_EventButtonInnerWrapper ">
<div class="ipo-ClassificationHeader_EventButton ipo-ClassificationHeader_EventButton-selected ">Alle Events</div>
<div class="ipo-ClassificationHeader_EventButton ">Live-Bilder</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="ipo-ClassificationHeader_MarketsButtonOuterWrapper ">
<div class="ipo-ClassificationHeader_MarketsButtonWrapper ">
<div class="ipo-ClassificationHeader_MarketsButton ipo-ClassificationHeader_MarketsButton-transparent ">Alle Wettm&ouml;glichkeiten</div>
<div class="ipo-ClassificationHeader_MarketsButton ipo-InPlayClassificationMarketSelector ipo-ClassificationHeader_MarketsButton-selected ">
<div class="ipo-InPlayClassificationMarketSelector_DropDown ipo-InPlayClassificationMarketSelectorDropDown ip-DropDownContainer ">
<div class="ipo-InPlayClassificationMarketSelectorDropdownLabelContainer ">
<div class="ip-DropDownContainer_Button ipo-InPlayClassificationMarketSelectorDropDown_Button ipo-InPlayClassificationMarketSelectorDropDown_Button-1 ">Haupt-Wettm&ouml;glichkeiten</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="ipo-FavouritesContainer ">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="ipo-CompetitionRenderer ">
<div class="ipo-Competition ipo-Competition-open ">
<div class="ipo-CompetitionButton ">
<div class="ipo-CompetitionButton_NameLabel ipo-CompetitionButton_NameLabelHasMarketHeading ">Deutschland - 3. Liga</div>
<div class="ipo-CompetitionButton_MarketHeadingWrapper">
<div class="ipo-CompetitionButton_MarketHeadingLabel ">1X2</div>
<div class="ipo-CompetitionButton_MarketHeadingLabel ">N&auml;chstes Tor</div>
<div class="ipo-CompetitionButton_MarketHeadingLabel ">Tore - Spiel</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="ipo-Competition_FavouriteWrapper">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="ipo-FixtureRenderer ipo-Competition_Container ">
<div class="ipo-Fixture ipo-Fixture_CL1 ipo-Fixture-hastimer ipo-Fixture_MainMarkets ">
<div class="ipo-Fixture_TableRow ">
<div class="ipo-Fixture_ScoreDisplay ipo-ScoreDisplayStandard ">
<div class="ipo-ScoreDisplayStandard_Wrapper ">
<div class="ipo-InPlayTimer ">58:27</div>
<div class="ipo-TeamStack ">
<div class="ipo-TeamStack_Team"><span class="ipo-TeamStack_TeamWrapper ">1. FC Kaiserslautern</span>
<div class="ipo-SoccerTeamStack_TeamGoalMarker "><span class="ipo-SoccerTeamStack_TeamGoalMarkerSpan ">TOR</span></div>
</div>
<div class="ipo-TeamStack_Team"><span class="ipo-TeamStack_TeamWrapper ">Eintracht Braunschweig</span>
<div class="ipo-SoccerTeamStack_TeamGoalMarker "><span class="ipo-SoccerTeamStack_TeamGoalMarkerSpan ">TOR</span></div>
</div>
<div class="ipo-TeamStack_Team"><span class="ipo-TeamStack_TeamWrapper ipo-TeamStack_DrawWrapper">Unentschieden</span></div>
</div>
<div class="ipo-TeamPoints ">
<div class="ipo-TeamPoints_TeamScoresWrapper ">
<div class="ipo-TeamPoints_TeamScore ipo-TeamPoints_TeamScore-teamone ">0</div>
<div class="ipo-TeamPoints_TeamScore ipo-TeamPoints_TeamScore-teamtwo ">0</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="ipo-ScoreDisplayStandard_MediaButton ">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="ipo-MainMarkets ">
<div class="ipo-MainMarketRenderer ">
<div class="gl-ParticipantCentered gl-ParticipantCentered_NoHandicap ipo-AllMarketsParticipant gl-ParticipantCentered_BlankName "><span class="gl-ParticipantCentered_Odds">1.83</span></div>
<div class="gl-ParticipantCentered gl-ParticipantCentered_NoHandicap ipo-AllMarketsParticipant gl-ParticipantCentered_BlankName "><span class="gl-ParticipantCentered_Odds">11.00</span></div>
<div class="gl-ParticipantCentered gl-ParticipantCentered_NoHandicap ipo-AllMarketsParticipant gl-ParticipantCentered_BlankName "><span class="gl-ParticipantCentered_Odds">2.30</span></div>
</div>
<div class="ipo-MainMarketRenderer ">
<div class="gl-ParticipantCentered gl-ParticipantCentered_NoHandicap ipo-AllMarketsParticipant ipo-ParticipantNoGoal gl-ParticipantCentered_BlankName "><span class="gl-ParticipantCentered_Odds">1.72</span></div>
<div class="gl-ParticipantCentered gl-ParticipantCentered_NoHandicap ipo-AllMarketsParticipant ipo-ParticipantNoGoal gl-ParticipantCentered_BlankName "><span class="gl-ParticipantCentered_Odds">6.50</span></div>
<div class="gl-ParticipantCentered gl-ParticipantCentered_NoHandicap ipo-AllMarketsParticipant ipo-ParticipantNoGoal gl-ParticipantCentered_BlankName "><span class="gl-ParticipantCentered_Name">Kein 1.</span><span class="gl-ParticipantCentered_Odds">2.62</span></div>
</div>
<div class="ipo-MainMarketRenderer ">
<div class="gl-ParticipantCentered ipo-AllMarketsParticipant gl-ParticipantCentered_BlankName "><span class="gl-ParticipantCentered_Handicap">&Uuml; 0.5</span><span class="gl-ParticipantCentered_Odds">1.44</span></div>
<div class="gl-ParticipantCentered ipo-AllMarketsParticipant gl-ParticipantCentered_BlankName "><span class="gl-ParticipantCentered_Handicap">U 0.5</span><span class="gl-ParticipantCentered_Odds">2.62</span></div>
<div class="ipo-MainMarketRenderer_BlankParticipant ">&nbsp;</div>`
```

I want to get the "1.83" in here `<div class="gl-ParticipantCentered gl-ParticipantCentered_NoHandicap ipo-AllMarketsParticipant gl-ParticipantCentered_BlankName "><span class="gl-ParticipantCentered_Odds">1.83</span></div>`

*edit 13.03.2019*

Now i am receiving this message:

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: div.ipo-Competition:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(2)

*edit 14.03.2019*

Later, if its working to catch the rate, i would like to make a loop to get the rates of all games with x = 1->n "div:nth-child(x)".

*edit 16.03.2019*

Ok, since i didnt get forward this way i installed the Selenium IDE on Firefox, recorded just a click on a rate on that page.
Thats the result:

```
  "comment": "",
  "command": "click",
  "target": "css=.ipo-Competition:nth-child(2) .ipo-MainMarketRenderer:nth-child(1) > .gl-ParticipantCentered:nth-child(3) > .gl-ParticipantCentered_Odds",
  "targets": [
    ["css=.ipo-Competition:nth-child(2) .ipo-MainMarketRenderer:nth-child(1) > .gl-ParticipantCentered:nth-child(3) > .gl-ParticipantCentered_Odds", "css:finder"],
    ["xpath=//div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/span[2]", "xpath:position"],
    ["xpath=//span[contains(.,'5.00')]", "xpath:innerText"]´
```

So i tried to get these two ways of locators into my script and just make a click to see if he gets it, but still doesnt work:

```
 driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".ipo-Competition:nth-child(2) .ipo-MainMarketRenderer:nth-child(1) > .gl-ParticipantCentered:nth-child(3) > .gl-ParticipantCentered_Odds")).click();

   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/span[2]")).click();
```

Comment: Please post the html of the element from which you are trying to fetch the text

Comment: What error are you exactly facing?

Comment: its not getting the value in that span "1.83"
<div class="gl-ParticipantCentered gl-ParticipantCentered_NoHandicap ipo-AllMarketsParticipant gl-ParticipantCentered_BlankName "><span class="gl-ParticipantCentered_Odds">1.83</span></div>

Comment: Your locator is not correct. Can you post a link to the page? That would be the easiest way to see what is going on. We also need to know what you want to find... not just "1.83" because that value may change. You want to get the first cell in the table or the first value after a team named X or whatever.

Comment: That is the page: "https://www.bet365.com/#/IP/" i want to get the rate (the value at the moment selenium reads) that for example team one wins/tie/or team two wins.

Answer (score 1):

Just checking - Are you trying to get the value out of a button element ? I think you may need to try to capture it in a webElement object (org.openqa.selenium.WebElement). 
This is a sample from one of my old Cucumber Test cases which pulls the value from a button element.

```
WebElement okButton = driver.findElement(By.id("confirmOk"));
WebElement cancelButton = driver.findElement(By.id("confirmCancle"));
assertEquals(okButton.getText(),"OK");
assertEquals(cancelButton.getText(),"Cancel");
```

You can use either By.Id or By.Xpath or By.cssselector but I think you just need that one extra step to capture the value. Not sure if that answers your question.

Comment: Thx for your answer but i think i didnt write the question clearly in the beginning. By.id i think doesnt work with this page. By.class also didnt because several classes have the same name, so i tried to write in a list, but also didnt work. Jea so im hoping the xpath or css will help. I tried some ways but didnt work yet :(

Comment: Oh the html you gave is helpful. I don't see you're using an id attribute for your html section. I dont know how it would work with the span but I think you need to either do this: 
<div id='myId' class ='myClass' <span class='mySpanClass'</span>1.83</div>
or this: 
<div class ='myClass'<span id ='spanId' class='mySpanClass'</span>1.83</div>

and then that is the Id you would use. Either 'myId' from the first example, or 'spanId' from the 2nd. Because you don't specify an Id, it cannot find it when you do findBy.Id and it throws a "No Such Element Exception"

Comment: Also if you have several classes with the same name I think you can still use it by doing :
driver.findElements(By.class("classThatEveryoneUses")).get(0).getText()
driver.findElements(By.class("classThatEveryoneUses")).get(1).getText()

That should just return the 1st class element on the page, then the 2nd, etc.

Comment: Hey Josh thx for your endurance, tried it these ways but not getting any text, so i tried a record with Selenium IDE, since i can record there and when i run the record its working. But still not getting it with my script.

Answer (score -1):

So the problem is that you are declaring a string `value` as `null` and then in the next line doing `.getAttribute(value)` which is `.getAttribute(null)` in this case.

```
String value = null;
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(...)).getAttribute(value);
```

My guess is that you want to do something more like the below to get the text. You need to delete the first line, store the return in the `value` variable so that it will get printed.

```
// String value = null; <- DELETE THIS LINE
String value = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(...)).getText();
```

Comment: jea i tried this way before, but it didnt write the value "1.83" into the Test.txt

Comment: Also tried the following xpath which didnt get value either: String value = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/span[2]")).getText();

Comment: You need to update your code with my initial suggestion and run it again. That's at least one problem... the locator may be a whole other problem. Update the code in your question and the current error message received.

Comment: aight, sorry not familiar how to write here. updated everything and also wrote the error at thte end. says unable to locate, but i just copied it via firefox inspector.

Comment: You missed the `String value = ` at the start of the line.